# Spell vamp - unique?

Tags: league-of-legends

I don't really understand the `unique`-ness in LoL. Is it per item or per passive type? It doesn't seem like the internet fully agrees about this (it's not clear to me at least).

If I have both [the Hextech Revolver](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hextech_Revolver) (Unique: +12 % Spell Vamp) and [Will of the Acients](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients) (Unique: +20 % Spell Vamp) will my spell vamp be +32 % or 20 %?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uniqueness works in a couple of ways. If an item is unique (without a name, like Will of the Ancients (WOTA) or Hextech Revolver) then it will stack with each-other, giving a total of 32% in your example. However, if you upgraded that Revolver into a WOTA, your spell vamp will be only 20%. This being, if you have multiple of the same item, the unique effects will not stack. (Look in Youtube for examples of people stacking the Sunfire Cape in old Seasons - wreaked havok [Like this one](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DlR6J0r4LHHI&ei=gNanVLiDHaalmQWprYLQBg&usg=AFQjCNE_2kIeGJAHj2eRTGeKH8e3PZRm6w&sig2=fDe2CAkHXheKPAnhM86Hhw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.dGY)). Some items, like the Sheen / Lich Bane / Frozen Gauntlet / Trinity Force combo, have a name associated with the unique effect (called spellblade, in this instance). Uniquely named effects like so will not stack under any conditions.

TL:DR -

- Unique stats will not stack ON THE SAME ITEM (ie 2x WOTA), but are ok with two different items
- Items with a Unique - *name* skill will not stack under any condition

Comment: Maybe this deserves its own question, but the effects of spellblade are different depending on which item you have, i.e. frozen gauntlet procs a slow while sheen just adds to base damage so how exactly do they not stack? Does it just use the spellblade from the item you had first?

Comment: @clcto I think that question deserves a question on its own. :)

Comment: @clcto as [the lol wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frozen_Mallet) describes:

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms unique means its unique to that individual item once, so if you get more than one of the item you will not have that buff stack.