# Stacking Spellblade

Tags: league-of-legends

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/199183/77408) we know that stacking multiple items with the same named-unique effect do not stack. However, the Spellblade effect is different between the multiple items (listed below) that share the effect, so how exactly do they not stack? Does it just use the passive from the first item I got? For example, if I got an Iceborn Gauntlet followed by a Trinity Force would I get the TF or IG passive?

---

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Named_item_effect)

- Sheen - Basic attack deals bonus Physical damage equal to your base attack damage.
- Trinity Force - Basic attack deals bonus Physical damage equal to 200% of your base attack damage.
- Lich Bane - Your basic attack deals bonus Magic damage equal to 75% of your base attack damage + 50% of your ability power.
- Iceborn Gauntlet - Basic attack deals bonus Physical damage equal to 125% of your base attack damage to surrounding enemies and creates a field for 3 seconds that slows enemies inside by 35%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Spellblade Items do stack in a certain way, however I would not recommend stacking them.

You basically have the damage component and with Iceborn Gauntlet there's also the CC/AOE component.

The damage component deals singletarget damage based on the following order:

```
Lich Bane > Trinity Force > Iceborn Gauntlet > Sheen
```

Also if you have an Iceborn Gauntlet the AOE effect will always appear on a Spellblade proc, even if you have a Trinity Force or Lich Bane.

Let's say you have the following Items:

```
Lich Bane, Trinity Force, Iceborn Gauntlet
```

If you use an ability and attack someone after that, you will Deal 75% Base AD + 50% AP Magic damage to the Primary Target while also creating a slow-field that deals 125% Base AD Physical Damage from Iceborn Gauntlet. If you sell your Lichbane, you will deal 200% Base AD Physical damage to the primary target (and again the AOE) since TF still has a higher priority over Iceborn.

As you can see the effects do stack in a certain way, however it's not recommended to actually stack the items. If you already have a trinity force, you should probably go for Frozen Heart (similar Stats) or Frozen Mallet (similar Utility) instead of an Iceborn Gauntlet.

Comment: What's your source if i may ask?

Comment: @Taacoo Personal experience and [Lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity_Force)

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular order in which the abilities will supersede each other. I believe TF will beat FG which will beat LB, but I'm not sure. Would be super fun if they stacked, but if they did  no one would be able to play anything but ezreal.